# Adjacent button causing indent on the button below

Tags: html, css

HTML / JS

```
     <html>

   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
     <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

     <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">

     
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  

     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/job/create_job.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
     <div class="centered">
       <div class="child">
           <div style="position: relative;">
             <input type="submit" class="myFormButton" name="submit" value="Upload for training" />
             <button type="button" onclick="HelpButton()" style="position: absolute;top: 30%;"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></button>

           </div>
           <div id="helpText" style="display: none;">
             Supported file types: midi
           </div>
         
         <a id="existing_jobs_link" class="myButton" href="existing_jobs.html?user=">Existing Jobs</a>
       </div>
     </div>
     <br><br>
     <script>
       validate_user();

       function HelpButton() {
         var x = document.getElementById("helpText");
         if (x.style.display === "none") {
           x.style.display = "initial";
         } else {
           x.style.display = "none";
         }
       }

     </script>
   </body>

 </html>
```

CSS

```
.centered .child {
    /* Center entire body */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.myFormButton {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #000000;
    background-color:#000000;
    border-radius:16px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:8px 53px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000000;
    white-space: normal;
    margin: 10px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:350px;
    text-align:center;
}

.myButton:hover {
    background-color:#000000;
}

.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.myButton {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #000000;
    background-color:#000000;
    border-radius:16px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:8px 53px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000000;
    white-space: normal;
    margin: 10px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width:240px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: 40px

}

#existing_jobs_table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#logout_link {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1%;
    right: 1%;
    font-size: x-large;
}
```

[image]

I'm trying to center the buttons on a website that I'm working on. Initially it was fine but after adding  the help button to the side of "create a job" an indent is created on existing jobs. I would like the buttons to be inline (lined up).

How can I make "existing jobs" inline with "create a new job"?

Thanks for any help!

Here's the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2pg8wcxy/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I have aligned the two buttons.

1. Moved the `<a>` tag for second button in a separate `child` div
2. Removed 40 px left margin from `myButton` class

Please see the HTML and CSS from here

https://jsfiddle.net/h1oLrxsn/

CSS:

```
.centered .child {
    /* Center entire body */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.myFormButton {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #000000;
    background-color:#000000;
    border-radius:16px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:8px 53px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000000;
    white-space: normal;
    margin: 10px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:350px;
    text-align:center;
}

.myButton:hover {
    background-color:#000000;
}

.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.myButton {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #000000;
    background-color:#000000;
    border-radius:16px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:8px 53px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000000;
    white-space: normal;
    margin: 10px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width:240px;
    text-align:center;
    

}

#existing_jobs_table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#logout_link {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1%;
    right: 1%;
    font-size: x-large;
}
```